# How to read HTTP requests without flooding my API with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, swift3

I'm trying to make a simple messaging app using an API. Right now, I have a thread that checks a request each second and see if the number of messages have changed, but this causes so much trouble, the RAM is constantly going up and the  API becomes unresponsive because of the large number of requests. At the moment my code looks like this :

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "URL")!)
let session = URLSession.shared

public func thread()
        {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                while(true)
                {
                    self.request.httpMethod = "GET"
                    self.session.dataTask(with: self.request) {data, response, err in
                        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                        let data = json?["data"] as? [[String: Any]]
                        if((data?.count)! > self.nbMessages)
                        {
                            self.messages.removeAll()
                            for message in data! {
                                let text = message["message_body"] as? String
                                let creator = message["creator_id"] as? Int
                                self.messages.append([text!, String(creator!)])
                            }
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.nbMessages = (data?.count)!
                                self.TableView.reloadData()
                                let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.TableView.contentSize.height - self.TableView.frame.size.height)
                                self.TableView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: false)
                            }
                        }
                        }.resume()
                    usleep(2000)
                }
            }
        }
```

This works fine, I can send messages and see messages sent to me (with a decent delay), but my logic with the request at every 2 second is way off and I acknowledge it. I'm still learning Swift so I'd really appreciate some advises on this matter, thanks!

Comment: I think this is when you should be use push notifications...

Comment: In what way? My API gives me 2 endpoints : getmessages and sendmessage

Comment: I agree with @Honey, rather than running the function endlessly to watch for received messages, add a APNS capability to your backend to notify your app when a new message is available, only then your app can run a function to pull the new messages.

Comment: Did i understand right, that you are trying to implement kind of messenger here?

Comment: @JonathanBouchard to be honest I don't know the details, but just that you 1. have to configure a [payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html) to send a *silent* notification 2. [enable background modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693786/adding-background-mode-on-capabilities-tabs/42375094#42375094) for your app 3. in your app consume the payload so that once you receive it you run your get, set mesage or whatever you like. AFAIK to setup push notifications you need a developr acount

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev Well kinda yes, it's already working the chat works fine, but the constant requests makes it slow. I'll try the notification route.

Comment: @Honey If I try to send notifications to a device I have to get his token by asking the permission of the user to send notifications to his device, what if the user refuses?

Comment: @JonathanBouchard then you can only download it when the app is in foreground. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369) (specifically read the last paragraph). But normally apps like Whatsapp are working because users enable push notifications. If they don't...then still the notifications which trigger network calls can happen 'if the app is in foreground' otherwise nothing. But that's the same case for your current-bad solution ie it can't do anything other than forground

Comment: @Honey Would you say that using HTTP request is appropriate for the kind of app I am building? See Answer below

Comment: @JonathanBouchard I don't know about sockets. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736913/push-notification-vs-web-sockets-for-implementing-a-real-time-chat-app). Sockets might be too hard to implement...In all the interviews that I've done and job listings, I've never seen anyone looking for experience with sockets. Push notifications seem just fine. Yet don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you provide elaboration, saying that you are implementing a messenger. For that purpose simple HTTP requests are not appropriate approach. Instead, you want to introduce so-called socket connection. I dare quote myself from [another relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43077474/5690248):

> It's called socket-connections, at a glance it looks like a channel, that hosts on a server side, and any clients (devices) can join this channel (two or more, whatever you want). If device send a message to the server, it should broadcast the message toward all other participants (it can broadcast the message even to the sender itself, but with some meta-information so we can distiguish our own messages and ignore them).
>
> Thereby first of all you need server with socket connection established, then you can implement any of already existing solutions (e.g. https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream for iOS). Also you may want to take a look at AWS https://aws.amazon.com, as it has the socket connection service out of the box for the server side and required SDK for both Android and iOS platforms.